# Using createobject("Excel.application") to create excel 2007 application

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have 2 excel versions installed on my system. 2007 and 365.

when using

```
function open1()

set h = createobject("Excel.application")
h.visible = true
h.workbooks.add

end function
```

Excel 365 opens up. When I wanted to open excel 2007.

I tried searching for solution for this. but could not find any similar case.

Is there any specific way by which I can particularly open excel 2007 application?

Comment: There is no way to do that using `CreateObject` that I know of. It will just redirect to whatever the default version is. You'd need to use `Shell` and then find another way to get a reference to the application in question.

Comment: that is for excel 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next adapted way. No need to be function, if it does not return anything:

```
Sub open1()
  dim h as Object

  set h = createObject("Excel.application.12")
  h.visible = true
  h.workbooks.add
end Sub
```

For the other version try using `createObject("Excel.application.16")`. Otherwise, the default version is automatically chosen...

I cannot test it, since I never needed two different versions. But I did that with Corel versions, **which works in this way**. In Corel case there are some differences between the versions in terms of differently doing the same thing. I developed some applications and I needed to update all of them in case of required modifications.

Comment: Still opens excel 365